# adding errors to Django form errors.__all__

Tags: django, django-forms

How do I add errors to the top of a form after I cleaned the data? I have an object that needs to make a REST call to an external app (google maps) as a pre-save condition, and this can fail, which means I need my users to correct the data in the form. So I clean the data and then try to save and add to the form errors if the save doesn't work:

```
if request.method == "POST":
#clean form data
    try:
        profile.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("some_page", args=[some.args]))
    except ValueError:
        our_form.errors.__all__ = [u"error message goes here"]
return render_to_response(template_name, {"ourform": our_form,}, 
       context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This failed to return the error text in my unit-tests (which were looking for it in `{{form.non_field_errors}}`), and then when I run it through the debugger, the errors had not been added to the forms error dict when they reach the `render_to_response` line, nor anywhere else in the our_form tree. Why didn't this work? How am I supposed to add errors to the top of a form after it's been cleaned?

Answer (score 18):

You really want to do this during form validation and raise a ValidationError from there... but if you're set on doing it this way you'll want to access `_errors` to add new messages. Try something like this:

```
from django.forms.util import ErrorList

our_form._errors["field_name"] = ErrorList([u"error message goes here"])
```

Comment: I need the errors at the top of the form because it's not any one field that would cause this to fail (eg. I'm combining street+city+state+zipcode and geocoding it).

Comment: -1 because this does not address the OP's requirement of adding a *non-field* error. Also -1 because this assignment obliterates any errors that may have already existed for `_errors["field_name"]`.

Comment: Will this be a right way to do it ?

non_field_errors = []
self._errors['field_name'] = self._errors.get('field_name', [])
self._errors['field_name'] = self._errors['field_name'].append(_("field_name is invalid ")

#add anyy non field error
raise form.ValidationError(non_field_errors)

Answer (score 12):

Non field errors can be added using the constant `NON_FIELD_ERRORS` dictionary key (which is `__all__` by default):

```
from django import forms
errors = my_form._errors.setdefault(forms.forms.NON_FIELD_ERRORS, forms.util.ErrorList())
errors.append("My error here")
```

Comment: This causes a 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setdefault' for me. Probably my model is otherwise valid, and thus _errors is undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: @MartinProbst: this code must be run after a call to form.is_valid()

Answer (score 12):

In Django 1.7 or higher, I would do:

```
form.add_error(field_name, "Some message")
```

The method [`add_error`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error) was added in 1.7. The `form` variable is the form I want to manipulate and `field_name` is the specific field name or `None` if I want an error that is not associated with a specific field.

In Django 1.6 I would do something like:

```
from django.forms.forms import NON_FIELD_ERRORS

errors = form._errors.setdefault(field_name, form.error_class())
errors.append("Some message")
```

In the code above `form` is the form I want to manipulate and `field_name` is the field name for which I want to add an error. `field_name` can be set to `NON_FIELD_ERRORS` to add an error not associated with a specific field. I use `form.error_class()` to generate the empty list of error messages. This is how Django 1.6 internally creates an empty list rather than instantiate `ErrorList()` directly.

Comment: @Louis, mine is 1.8, I tried "form.add_error(field_name, "Some message")", then it reports "'MyForm' object has no attribute 'addError'", do I need to import anything apart from "from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist,ValidationError"?

Answer (score 9):

You should raise the validationerror.

Why not put the verification within the form's clean method

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    def clean(self):
        try:
            #Make a call to the API and verify it works well
        except:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Your address is not locatable by Google Maps')
```

that way, you just need the standard `form.is_valid()` in the view.

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be more systemic, this update can happen when other parts of the system try to alter the data, so it's beyond just the one form.

Otherwise, you're right, the form would be ideal.

Comment: Shouldn't always use inherited forms to do validations ?

Answer (score 8):

You're almost there with your original solution. Here is a base Form class I built which allows me to do the same thing, i.e. add non-field error messages to the form:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.util import ErrorDict
from django.forms.forms import NON_FIELD_ERRORS 

class MyBaseForm(forms.Form):
    def add_form_error(self, message):
        if not self._errors:
            self._errors = ErrorDict()
        if not NON_FIELD_ERRORS in self._errors:
            self._errors[NON_FIELD_ERRORS] = self.error_class()
        self._errors[NON_FIELD_ERRORS].append(message)

class MyForm(MyBaseForm):
    ....
```

All my forms extend this class and so I can simply call the add_form_error() method to add another error message.

Comment: +1 for checking that attributes exist and not assuming `error_class()` is an ErrorList. You can use this method of appending non-field error messages just as well without subclassing Form, which may suit other use cases.

Comment: 1.7 has something like this built in.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how horrible of a hack this is (I've only really worked on two Django projects up until this point) but if you do something like follows you get a separate error message that is not associated with a specific field in the model:

```
form = NewPostForm()
if something_went_horribly_wrong():
  form.errors[''] = "You broke it!"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the validation pertains to the data layer, then you should indeed not use form validation. Since Django 1.2 though, there exists a similar concept for Django models and this is certainly what you shoud use. See [the documentation for model validation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#id1).