# Externally add form errors in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django form that will add an entry to a database with a unique constraint on one of the columns.  If the submission happens to attempt creation of a duplicate, I get a `django.db.utls.IntegrityError` stating I violated the unique constraint (thankfully).

When processing Django forms, there are a number of ways to validate:

1. Override the form class' `clean` method
2. Override the form class' `clean_<field>` method

If the `clear_<field>` method raises a `django.forms.ValidationError`, the error message will be appended to a list in the `_errors` dictionary under the field's name. When using the `clean` method, errors should be [manually inserted](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-subclasses-and-modifying-field-errors) into the `_errors` dict.

Now, the `clean` and `clean_<field>` methods don't sound like a nice place to put code that has side effects, and I fear that checking at this moment whether the value is unique does not guarantee I won't get `IntegrityError`s. I would prefer to actually try and create the row in the database and signal a form error when a constraint is violated.

My main problem is that forms expose a public property `errors` which is **read-only**. Therefore, I should, according to the docs, add a method in my form that does all the work, try to insert in the database and register an error when an `IntegrityError` is raised. Because the action that processes the form after validation requires lots of other data, I don't want to put the code inside the form class itself.

Is there any other (documented or not) way to go about adding an entry in the `errors` dict from outside the class, or should I simply access the `_errors` "private" variable and be happy with that? I know this sounds like an OOP breach, but creating an extra method just to access this "private" variable does not seem to me like it shields anybody from anything.

**Edit:**
Seems like someone else already raised [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235146/adding-errors-to-django-form-errors-all), but it seems the answers pointed to manual insertion into `_errors`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding errors to Django form errors.\_\_all\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235146/adding-errors-to-django-form-errors-all)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For now, a simple solution is the following:

```
try:
    # Try to save model instance, which might throw `IntegrityError`.
    # ...
except django.db.utils.IntegrityError:
    # The form passed validation so it has no errors.
    # Use the `setdefault` function just in case.
    errors = django.forms.util.ErrorList()
    errors = form._errors.setdefault(
        django.forms.forms.NON_FIELD_ERRORS, errors)
    errors.append('Sorry, this username is already in use.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think adding the method to the form is quite reasonable. The ModelForm class, which has a save() method which does the logic of saving the created instance to the database. If your form can inherit from ModelForm (or just add a save() method to your form), you'll still be well within "djangonian" standards.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: I know it's reasonable, but I can't do that in this particular case. The form is used in different places and in one case, the form's data is passed to some other entity via a polymorphic invocation. In the current design, the form *should not* know what to do with the data!